# Links are not working on Magento 2 on Front End theme

Tags: magento2

I installed **quickstart Magento** with **Venus Floristy theme** on **cPanel**. Everything is running fine except for **links there**. When I go to homepage **`mydomain.co.uk`** its working fine and store is opening.

But when I click on menu links, Magento is giving error. Let say I am going to contact page so on clicking contact in menu its giving error and making link as

> http://mydomain.co.uk**en/contact/?SID=ocv7q4bfjnf8r6ura9bpvsnmh3**

And links are not working. **Magento** is automatically adding en in domain as you can see above and page is not opening but when I manually modily en like

> http://mydomain.co.uk**/en/contact/?SID=ocv7q4bfjnf8r6ura9bpvsnmh3**

now page is opening and working fine. Can you tell me what going wrong there.

And store is also not working when I try to go www.mydomain.co.uk

Answer (score 2):

You don't set Store base url and  link url properly.

Check core_config_data table in database.

***And run  below query and see what result will come***

> SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` where path in
>   ('web/unsecure/base_url','web/secure/base_url','web/unsecure/base_link_url','web/secure/base_link_url')

And you will find your base url and link url like

> http://mydomain.co.uk

**Instead of**

> http://mydomain.co.uk/

An `slash(/)`is ***missing  this fields value***.You  *should add the slash and then flush the cache*.

[image]